# Retrofit response body sometimes error, but sometimes success

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm getting some error when post some data.

My app could register a new user, send data register to server and then return a result.

result if register is success

```
{
   "res": "success"
}
```

result if register is failed

```
{
   "res": "customer id not found"
}
```

Here my piece of code for post data

```
Register register = new Register(nameStr, emailStr, phoneStr, passStr, rePassStr,customerIDStr );
    Call<ResultRegister> call = apiInterface.registration(register);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResultRegister>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResultRegister> call, Response<ResultRegister> response) {
            String responseString;
            responseString = response.body().getRes();
            if(responseString.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Register Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Fragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.wrap_login_container, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Register Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResultRegister> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            call.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check your network connection and internet permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Everything is fine if the register return success, but if register return error a null pointer exception appears, pointing to this line:

```
responseString = response.body().getRes();
```

**EDIT**

this is my ResultRegister class

```
public class ResultRegister {
@SerializedName("res")
String res;

public String getRes() {
    return res;
}

public void setRes(String res) {
    this.res = res;
}
```

}

Any solution??

Comment: webservice and data that you are posting?

Comment: i have no access to webservice

Comment: then how are you passing data to webservice?

Comment: everything is fine, data for passing is correct, nothing error except the return value if register is failed

Comment: i am a freelance, a android developer, hired by a company. They only provide webservice documentation, so i have no access to open webservice's file

Comment: that is right then.. if registration is failed server will respond you with different data.

Comment: so that is the possible problems, i will check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. The main problem is when the register is failed, the error code is 500 (internal error server). So the `response.body()` is `null`.